# Finding all possible $(d,n)$ pairs given $k$ edges.

Tags: graph-theory

I am having trouble solving this specific problem.

"A simple graph has $21$ edges, and each vertex has the same degree, $d$.
Find all possible values for $d$ and the corresponding number of nodes $n$."

By Handshaking Lemma, the $\sum deg(V)$$= 2|E| = 2(21) = 42$. Yet I'm kinda stuck on how to find all possible pairs $(d,n)$ which produces a simple graph.

Additionally, is there an underlying proof for the solution of this problem?

Comment: **Hint**: In the graph with $n$ vertices, each with degree $d$,  the sum of the vertex degrees is $n \cdot d$.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak. Thank you for the insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the simple graph you have in mind. It has $d$ edges attached to each of the $n$ vertices, and so there are $n \cdot d$ edges in the entire graph. Every edge shares exactly two vertices, so there are $2 \cdot 21$ "directed" edges. So we want $n \cdot d = 42$. Note that we must exclude the case where $n = 1$. (Why? Recall the definition of a simple graph.)

Thus we are left with the equation $n \cdot d = 42$, $n > 1$. You are looking for the number of valid integral solutions to this equation.

Comment: Thank youu so much!!